# Don't allow time change React-DatePicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, react-datepicker

I'm using the [React-DatePicker](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker) package along with momentjs to let the user pick a date on an input which looks like this:

[image]

I want to display the time, but not let the user change it directly from the `<input>`. My date picker has an `onChange()` function:

```
onExpirationDateChange(date) {
   this.setState({selectedTime: date.unix()});
}
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve displaying the time, but not letting the user change it?

Comment: Are you trying to set a specific time everytime, like no matter which date they pick, it will always show that date with the time set as 11:59am?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this way:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("inputdate")[0].setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
```

As you can problably tell, it's set to readonly, so one can't write in the input anymore but they can still copy the text if needed.

Answer (score 0):

As per the examples on this page: https://reactdatepicker.com/

You might try this to prevent the users from selecting times...

```
<DatePicker
  selected={this.state.startDate}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  showTimeSelect
  excludeTimes={[moment().hours(17).minutes(0), moment().hours(18).minutes(30), moment().hours(19).minutes(30)], moment().hours(17).minutes(30)}
  dateFormat="LLL"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself. Just set `readOnly` on picker and make sure to not include time select option.